# combining logical operations in indexing array - Julia

Tags: indexing, julia, logical-operators

Given a 1D array in Julia, find all elements which are between a (= 4) and b( = 7), in place.

```
a = 4;b = 7;
x = collect(1:10)
x[isless.(x,a)]
```

will find all the elements in array which are less than a = 4.

How to combine two logical operations in indexing.

```
 x[isless.(x,a) && !isless.(x,b)]
```

is not working out.

Comment: you need a dot `.` [before](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/negation-of-boolean-array/16159) the `!` because it is an operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are OK with `<` operator instead of `isless` (which is most likely the case unless you work with `NaN`, `missing`, or `-0.0`) then you can write:

```
julia> x[a .< x .< b]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
```

Alternatively you can use `filter`:

```
julia> filter(v -> a < v < b, x)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
```

which brings me to the reason why I added this comment. You asked for an *in place* operation. This is not possible with indexing, but you can achieve it with `filter!` if you work with `Vector`:

```
julia> filter!(v -> a < v < b, x)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6

julia> x
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use broadcast `&&` (or, on older Julia versions, `&`):

```
julia> x[isless.(x,b) .&& (!isless).(x,a)]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 4
 5
 6

julia> x[isless.(x,a) .& (!isless).(x,b)]
Int64[]
```

The other thing to be careful about is the precedence of `!` vs `.` -- you'll either need to use `(!isless).(x, a)` or `.!isless.(x, a)` to get the right broadcasting behaviour.